# Manage multiple trackbars with the same callback function opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering if in opencv is possible to do something like this. I would like to call the same callback function onChange on each trackbar and inside onChange() extract in some way which one of the 3 slider changed.

```
cv::createTrackbar("bar_0", "window", &bSliderValue1, 100, onChange, (void*)&data);
cv::createTrackbar("bar_1", "window", &bSliderValue2, 100, onChange, (void*)&data);
cv::createTrackbar("bar_2", "window", &bSliderValue3, 100, onChange, (void*)&data);
```

The function onChange is like this:

```
static void onChange(int value, void* userdata)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add user data with an ID for the trackbar

```
struct Userdata {
    int sliderId;
    std::string sliderName;
};

const Userdata userdata0 {0, "bar_0"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_0", "window", &bSliderValue1, 100, onChange, const_cast<Userdata*>(&userdata0));

const Userdata userdata1 {1, "bar_1"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_1", "window", &bSliderValue2, 100, onChange, const_cast<Userdata*>(&userdata1));

const Userdata userdata2 {2, "bar_2"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_2", "window", &bSliderValue3, 100, onChange, const_cast<Userdata*>(&userdata2));

static void onChange(int value, void* userdata)
{
    const auto &slider = const_cast<const Userdata&>(*static_cast<Userdata*>(userdata));
    auto sliderId = slider.sliderId;
    auto sliderName = slider.sliderName;
}
```

You should replace the C casts by C++ casts.

Here is an example without const.

```
struct Userdata {
    int sliderId;
    std::string sliderName;
};

Userdata userdata0 {0, "bar_0"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_0", "window", &bSliderValue1, 100, onChange, &userdata0);

Userdata userdata1 {1, "bar_1"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_1", "window", &bSliderValue2, 100, onChange, &userdata1);

Userdata userdata2 {2, "bar_2"};
cv::createTrackbar("bar_2", "window", &bSliderValue3, 100, onChange, &userdata2);

static void onChange(int value, void* userdata)
{
    const auto &slider = *static_cast<Userdata*>(userdata);
    auto sliderId = slider.sliderId;
    auto sliderName = slider.sliderName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hellp, i'll try it, but can i do without passing a const? because i am passing an object and i would like to modify some fields